# Slick js carousel flickers while page is loading

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom, slick.js

I've set up a minimal example using a simple HTML + Bootstrap + Slick JS carousel.

The problem is that every time the page starts loading, slick js carousel makes and annoying flicker/blinking.

I've set up an example here:

http://rewind9.com/flicker/examples/starter-template/index.html

I've verified and the order scripts are being loaded is correct. Here is how I call the carousel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });
  });
</script>
```

I thought this was a CSS issue so I even tried hiding the overflow on the main div, without success.

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Any ideas what else I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is correct, I see on slick carousel demo page the same issue http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @Johann in your script theres a code ` $('.carousel').fadeIn()` before `carousel` init. Verify if that is causing a problem. Also remove `,` after `autoplaySpeed` option in `init`

Comment: Another you may have to consider is image load time. Images should load before you show the carousel. I would recommend async load for images. Check out if it works out for you.